# No cons operator or curried cons function in F#?

Tags: list, f#, cons

We can write `3 + 4` or `(+) 3 4` in F# and get the same result, and this works for most operators.

Why is it that the cons operator `::` behaves differently?  E.g. if I run

`(::) 1 [2;3]`

I get

`error FS0010: Unexpected symbol '::' in expression`

whereas I'd want to get [1;2;3].

On a related note, why is `List.Cons` not curried? Is there no built-in cons function of type `'T -> 'T list -> 'T list`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually (::) is not an operator. It's a union case.  At least that's the way F# creators defined it:

```
type List<'T> = 
   | ([])  :                  'T list
   | (::)  : Head: 'T * Tail: 'T list -> 'T list
and 'T list = List<'T>
```

Which makes sense:  A list can be either empty or have a head and a tail.

Regarding `List.Cons` I agree, it should have signature `'T->'T list ->'T list` rather than `'T*'T List->'T list`.